# How to add instance name to String using this-keyword?

Tags: scala

I'm searching for quite a while to get around the following problem:
Every instance of my class "B" uses a method to store a Seq "output" in a file.

```
class B extends IO {
    private var b = 0.0
    var output = Seq(0.0)

    def add(a:Int) = {
        b += a
        output :+= b
        WriteToFile(fileName, output)
    }
}
```

And theres also a trait where the WriteToFile-method is:

```
trait IO {
    def WriteToFile(fileName:String, data:Seq[Int]) = {
        create file and name it something like: fileName+this+".m"
    }
}
```

So every time the method "add" is called on an instance on class "B", the output-sequence is stored in a file. I want to create a different file for every instance of class "B". But when I create an instance like

```
val x = new B
```

the this-keyword in the WriteToFile-Method just adds "Bank()" to the fileName. So, how can alter the code in such a way that every new instance of class "B" creates its own file? And how can I alter the WriteToFile-Method in such way that the name of the instance (here "x") is added to the String determining the fileName?

Comment: Objects (instances of classes) do not have names. So there is no such thing as the "instance name". *Variables* have names, but variables are *references* to objects, and you can have multiple variables that refer to the same object. So, what you want is not possible - you have a misunderstanding about names of variables and objects.

Comment: You can add instance name only if you define instance name in your class. I adds Bank() probably because your type Bank is a case class, which defines toString for you. Usually new Object().toString will print you jvm - hashcode that is useful next to nothing.

Comment: Thank you for the comments. I guess, now I got the concept of this. This was very helpful. Especially yours, vitalii!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd discourage you from trying naming object instances according to the names of your variables. [Variables](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Variable_%28computer_science%29) are very different from [references](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reference_%28computer_science%29). For example, let's have this piece of code:

```
def foo: Object = {
    val x = new Object;
    val y = x;
    return x;
}
```

This method creates some new `Object`. The reference to the object is assigned to variable `x` and then to variable `y`. So now we have one objects, but referenced by two variables. And when the method returns, the object still exists, but perhaps with variable referencing it.

So naming the object by a variable that's holding it isn't very meaningful - there can be multiple such variables, or none, and it changes during the lifetime of the object.

Instead, I'd suggest you to create your own mechanism for generating names. One possibility is to use an atomic counter (so that it can be safely used from multiple threads):

```
trait AtomicName {
  val name = "prefix" + AtomicName.newId;
}
object AtomicName extends App {
  import java.util.concurrent.atomic.AtomicInteger;

  private val counter = new AtomicInteger(0);

  protected def newId = counter.getAndIncrement;
}
```

Now everything extending `AtomicName` will have a unique name.

Answer (score 1):

```
trait IO {
  def myName = 
    this.getClass.getName.split("\\$",-1).dropRight(1).lastOption.getOrElse("")
}

class B extends IO {
  var output = Seq(0.0)
}

object x extends B {
  def test { println(myName + " has " + output) }
}
```

Note that you must use `object x` instead of `val x`, and this does contain some overhead, plus it is lazy--`x` gets created the first time its contents are used, not the first time it's stated.  (If you call `myName` on something that is not an object, it will give you an empty string.)

I think this is a bad idea, but this is how to do it.